# how to copy a number on mouse click

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a simple .bat program which copies a number on my clipboard when i execute this bat file. so that I can paste it anywhere. it should work like a tally counter and should increment the number every time I click on it.

here is what I have tried so far, but it copies "1000++1" to my clipboard

```
echo|set /p=1000++1|clip
```

Comment: You would have to have the last number incremented saved into a file.  Then read the file, increment the number, write it back out to the file and then send it to your clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Squashman said :

```
@echo off
if not exist count.txt echo 0 > count.txt
set /p $count=< count.txt
set /a $Count+=1
echo %$count% | clip
echo %$count% > count.txt
```